# Odd Even Function NOT assigning class to my posts in loop

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to style my odd and even posts in the wordpress loop differently.  On multiple websites and forums, I have been seeing this code:

```
function oddeven_post_class ( $classes ) {

    global $current_class;
    $classes[] = $current_class;
    $current_class = ($current_class == 'odd') ? 'even' : 'odd';
    return $classes;

}

add_filter ( 'post_class' , 'oddeven_post_class' );

global $current_class;

$current_class = 'odd';
```

But this is NOT working.  When I inspect, there is no odd or even assigned to my posts.

Live website:  http://www.acetronaut.com

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @jhpratt this is wordpress, so there is no way for an MCVE .. actually it's an MCVE ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to mark your posts as odd or even for styling.

Even though it's possible to do it in both php (when you're iterating through your posts) and in JavaScript, relying on DOM structure, I personally prefer to do it where styling should be done: in CSS, especially since it has a special selector for this purpose: [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

In your case, here's a CSS sample that will change the appearance of your odd posts, on front page:

```css
.acetronaut-rem-fi:nth-child(2n) .acetronaut-post-content-rem {
    background-color: #212121;
    color: white;
}
.acetronaut-rem-fi:nth-child(2n) .acetronaut-post-content-rem * {
    color: white;
}
```

The "key" part is `:nth-child(2n)`.

And here's how this should render:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you are viewing an older version of my website.  I have scrapped those loops and started from scratch.  Try hard resetting or clearing cache?  I will try your suggestion though.  Any thoughts on why my php isn't working?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd say your template is not calling `post_class()`. See a basic implementation in [#user-contributed-notes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/#user-contributed-notes). To test, simply run a `die()` inside your function.

Comment: If the function does trigger, make sure you're inside a loop and `$post` is global where you're calling it.

Comment: // Yup!  I wasn't calling post_class() in my loop!  I fixed it using this code. `<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>`